# How to sign a console application in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I am trying to run some code to add to my project, but it wont work as intended. The code is on this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ics/c-registering-with-windows-firewall-ownership

It requires that I run it with the '/integritycheck' linker flag. Doing so prevents the resulting exe from running.

So far i have tried signing the exe with a self signed code signing certificate, which I added to the store of trusted certificates. Even then after signing it and verifying the signature, the exe still does not run.
Checking the 'Digital Signatures' tab on the properties page of the exe shows that everything is all good.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Ie3.png) is what it looks like.

When i try to run the exe, a dialog box shows up saying something along the lines of "Windows could not verify the digital signature of this file". As stated above, to my knowledge, I have signed it properly, therefore the dialog box should not show up, and let the program run.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157677/how-to-sign-visual-studio-empty-project-executable-for-integritycheck-linker

Comment: Oh, oops. But that question is still unanswered

Comment: How are you signing the executable? How are you generating the self-signed certificate? Have you marked it as a leaf certificate?

Comment: I got it working, check out my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question Jabberwocky linked led me to the page:

https://www.meziantou.net/generate-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing.htm

Some more personal research led me to finding articles telling me to sign with the `/ph` option in signtool, and to run windows in test mode. While test mode isn't ideal in my opinion, it atleast allows me to test the code.

Using these together allowed me to actually run the executable.

Posting this here in case anyone else comes across this kind of question.